# Python/Selenium couple of problems

Tags: python, selenium

So here is my code without the necessary imports

```
results = []
with open("al.txt") as inputfile:
   for line in inputfile:
       results.extend(line.strip().split(',')) 

x = random.choice(results)
chromedriver = "C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(x)
time.sleep(10)
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
b = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")
c = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input")
time.sleep(1)
x.send_keys("x")
time.sleep(1)
b.send_keys("y")
time.sleep(1)
c.click()
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("vB_Editor_QR_textarea")
post = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/div[2]/input[10]")
time.sleep(2)
element.send_keys("dsada")
time.sleep(1)
post.click()
time.sleep(30)
```

So the first problem is : im trying to make a loop for this but whenever i try to add "while True:" the code gets broken and gives indent errors

the second problem is : the driver waits too much to load, i want it to skip the loading part and do the tasks whenever it recognizes the elements

i will be really appriciated if anybody can answer theese.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem - **it's a basics of python**. How can you write anything with a bit of complexity without knowing basics? Just take a look at few first pages of any python tutorial. Any construction, in your case - while loop can see the block of code, which belongs to, only if it made with indentation (at least 2 spaces):

```
# Wrong:
i = 0
while i < 5:
print i
i += 1

# Correct:
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print i
    i += 1
```

The second problem - look at **wait.until**, but after learning basics of python :)

Comment: Referring to the "basics of python" is not an answer, better yet be a comment.

Comment: i've tried my code with making 4 spaces while using loop that is the reason it's confused me it still gave indent errors

Comment: It will be better if you show to us your code which produces that error.

Comment: @KobiK Learning the "basics of python" *is* the answer. If the OP knew the basics, he wouldn't be asking this question.